# vim bin mode view

Tags: vim, hex, mode, bin

How to view file in bin mode in VIM?
example:
*0101010100111010010

1101001001000100001

11000110111010111010*
I know how to view file in hex mode.
Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Same as hex, just pass `-b` flag to `xxd`:

```
:%!xxd -b
```